# Need to press return in each cell of excel to convert cell format to date after exporting it from Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, date, datetime, openpyxl

I am facing an issue in converting string to date format through Openpyxl. I have written a code where a date is entered in each cell of excel but when I open the excel, I have to press 'return' or 'enter' button in each cell to convert the cell format from General to Date. I am unable to figure out the fix. Below is the code and the output:

```
from openpyxl.cell import cell

File = 'D:\\Saurabh\\My research\\Python\\BSE\\Historical price\\Opto Circuits\\532391_Delivery%.xlsx'

from openpyxl import*
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook(File)
ws = wb.active
print (ws['A1'].value)
import datetime
for i in range(2, len(ws['A'])):
    if(isinstance(ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value, datetime.datetime))==True:
        x = str(ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value).split('-')
        x2 = str(x[2]).split(' 00:00:00')
        ws.cell(row=i, column=16).value = str(x2[0] + '/' + x[1] + '/' + x[0])
    else:
        x = str(ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value).split('/')
        ws.cell(row=i, column=16).value = x[1]+'/'+x[0]+'/'+x[2]
    wb.save('D:\Saurabh\My research\Python\BSE\Historical price\Opto Circuits\Opto Circuits_clean.xlsx')
    wb.close()




Output:

01/04/2020
01/05/2020
```

I need the output to be in date format. Please help.

Comment: I see that you are explicitly writing a string in the cell value. If you need it to be treated as date, you should set value to an object of date.

Comment: Thanks AKS. I've been trying to convert it to a date object using datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x[2]+x[1]+x[0]), '%Y/%m/%d') but I'm getting an error time data '(x[2]+x[1]+x[0])' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'

Comment: You do need the `/` in `str(x[2]+x[1]+x[0]`, right?

Comment: I removed '/' because strptime needs the string to be without '/ and have string format of 'yyyymmdd'. My current output is '20200104' which I'm trying to convert to date format in excel

Comment: Actually you were right AKS. It does need '/'. The error was coming because I had not used the strptime function on my 'if' condition and applied it only on 'else' condition. Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: Be careful, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: Sure AMC. I am a beginner, so this is a useful tip.